# RouterOS v7 usermanger limitation not working as expected; goes to “unlimited” even with a limit being set

Tags: mikrotik

I'm using MikroTik RB2011 with RouterOS v7.

When I give 180MB data limit for a user in limitation then its going unlimited.

I am give 188743680 bytes for 180MB data but it's going unlimited.

[image]

Comment: Could you please use the EDIT button and add some formatting and grammar, to begin with, and also further information showing the research you've done, the things you've tried, and things like a clearer explanation of the problem.

Comment: @Ramhound did you miss a zero in your calculations? 188,743,680 should be closer to 180mb than 18.8mb.